# redhat cygwin vs cygwin? any difference?

Tags: windows, cygwin

I just notice that there is a redhat cygwin at http://www.redhat.com/services/custom/cygwin/ , is there any difference ?

1 . redhat builds cygwin so its faster.

```
(5:15:46 AM) adamramadhan: version ?
(5:15:53 AM) adamramadhan: 1.8 and 1.7.7 ?
(5:15:59 AM) adamramadhan: why can that happen ?
(5:16:17 AM) snoopy left the room ("Saliendo").
(5:16:30 AM) r15 [~anuj@122.177.232.122] entered the room.
(5:17:00 AM) MartinCo: adamramadhan, because RHAT builds cygwin, the released version are behind the lates build
```

Comment: +1, I've always wondered this. I've used both and the only thing I've noticed is the Red Hat branding in their installer. Note that Cygwin is sponsored/developed by Red Hat.

Comment: One difference I just ran into is that the RH Cygwin seems to have a different repository from the other Cygwin. For instance, git is no where to be found (by my eyes and search) in the RH Cygwin... curious.

Comment: wew you are right, but we can build it. however i still want to know if there is any more differences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Wikipedia page <sub>I've changed the links for this context,</sub>

> [Cygwin](http://www.redhat.com/services/custom/cygwin/) was originally developed by Cygnus Solutions, which was later acquired by [Red Hat](http://www.redhat.com/services/custom/cygwin/support/). It is free and open source software, released under the GNU General Public License version 2. Today it is maintained by employees of Red Hat, NetApp and many other volunteers.

Red Hat Cygwin is at release 1.8 at the moment (**cygwin.dll**),
This is when the [regular Cygwin](http://sources.redhat.com/cygwin/) is at release 1.7.7 (**cygwin1.dll**).

> The Cygwin library, utilities, and numerous applications are available for free download under the terms of the GPL. Red Hat offers developer and user support for this software, as well as license contracts for the Cygwin library and its utilities. The [Red Hat Cygwin official installation utility](ftp://ftp.ges.redhat.com/private/releng/cygwin-1.8/rhsetup.exe) can be used for both initial installation and automated updating.

From the Cygwin FAQ,
[Can I bundle Cygwin with my product for free](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin/1.5/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.using.bundling-cygwin)?

> Only if you comply with Cygwin's [license](http://cygwin.com/license.html) very carefully. If you choose to distribute cygwin1.dll, you must be willing to distribute the exact source code used to build that copy of cygwin1.dll as per the terms of the GPL. If you ship applications that link with cygwin1.dll, you must either provide those applications' source code under a GPL-compatible license, *or* purchase a cygwin license from Red Hat.

[Can I build a Cygwin program that does not require cygwin1.dll at runtime](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin/1.5/faq/faq-nochunks.html#faq.programming.static-linking)?

> No. If your program uses the Cygwin API, then your executable cannot run without cygwin1.dll. In particular, it is not possible to statically link with a Cygwin library to obtain an independent, self-contained executable.
>
> If this is an issue because you intend to distribute your Cygwin application, then you had better read and understand http://cygwin.com/licensing.html, which explains the licensing options. **Unless you purchase a special commercial license from Red Hat, then your Cygwin application must be Open Source**.

Comment: redhat website says geos for regular cygwin, is redhat cygwin is ended?

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Redhat Cygwin, and Cygwin, is that the Redhat Cygwin is no longer supported. The Redhat Cygwin installer is no longer advertised on the Redhat web portal, however, the old link to the exe still works. The RedHat Global Engineering Services team will support those who have paid for a support license, however, from what I can see the Redhat Cygwin version is dead, or dying.